# trigger insertion from within server code of MongoDB

Tags: c++, mongodb, insert, server-side

I need to trigger insertion to a collection from within the server code without involving client driver.

I wrote the following code:

```
BatchedCommandRequest request (BatchedCommandRequest::BatchType_Insert);
request.setNS("tutorial.test");
request.setOrdered(false);
BSONObj myObject = BSON(GENOID << "namespace"<< "theNameSpace" << "query" << "myQuery" << "fields" << "theQueryFields" );
request.getInsertRequest()->addToDocuments(myObject);
```

and expected that every time the function that I placed this code inside is running, this part of code will insert the myObject document to the tutorial.test collection, but it doesn't.
Any idea what do I do wrong? and how to do it?

Comment: I'm sorry - could you clarify what you want to do? You want a call from the client, like an insert, to trigger another insert purely on the database side?

Comment: I want to develop a code, such that when a query comes in, for example a "find" function, then automatically an insertion will take place to a separated collection and save a record of the query. Something like profiling does in MongoDB. 
But I can not find the proper code for it.

Comment: You'll need to insert the query to another collection with using the client. You can't have the server so it automatically for you - except via profiling. Why can't you use profiling if you want to track queries?

Comment: Because I am trying to develop a tool which I like to test its functionality on MongoDB code. So I will appreciate if you can point me to the part of MongoDB code where profiling is actually coded, so that I can mimic its usage or at least see if I can make the changes that I need to it?

Comment: this is more like an exercise for me to gain a better understanding of MongoDB code structure  from a developer point of view and see how I can develop new code around it. Unless this first part could have been done with profiling.